# Are Type Casts an Atomic Operation in Swift? - BAD_ACCESS_ERROR

Tags: swift, concurrency

Let's say I am trying to access a shared variable between two threads. One thread will continuously set the shared variable to either nil or to the reference of an object that can be deallocated.

### Class Code

```
class ConcurrentPrinter {
    var value: AnyObject?
}
```

### Thread one

```
// called 30 times per second
func setter(){
    value = shouldSet ? nil : valueArray[0]
    // where the value is an instance type
}
```

### Thread two

```
// also called 30 times per second
func getter() {
    if value != nil {
        guard let desiredObject = value as? desiredObjectType else {
        return
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am getting a Bad_Address error in the guard statement when it tries to cast value into the desiredObjectType. Is this happening because the cast operation gets the address of value and then it gets deallocated before it can finish the cast operation?

Comment: Likely the crash is due to the fact that `value` gets deallocated on the other thread while used on the crasher thread.

Comment: any ideas on how to refactor the code to be immune to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The answer is to place each of the operations on a DispatchQueue and run each of the code using an async request. This ensures that the two pieces of code are running simultaneously